# Problem with Pyserial when using Xbee and GPS on rasp pi 3B+

Tags: pi-3b+, serial, gps, xbee

i am currently trying to get some data from gps and try to send it through Xbee to a pc. To do this, i was using multiprocessing. At first getting the GPS data and sending data through Xbee was done on seperate process/thread, but through process of trouble shooting down below is the result of the current code that handle both the gps and sendsing Xbee data in a single process.

```
def gps(result_gps, queue_signal,data_queue):  
ser = Serial("/dev/ttyS0",57600,bytesize = EIGHTBITS,stopbits = STOPBITS_ONE, parity = PARITY_NONE)

while True:
    if (queue_signal.empty() and data_queue.empty()):
        
        my_sentence=ser.readline()
        print(my_sentence)
        data_formats = [b'$GPGGA']
        
        for format in data_formats:
            if format in my_sentence:
                try:
                    print(my_sentence)
                    my_sentence=my_sentence.decode('utf-8')
                    lat,lat_dir,lon,lon_dir,alt=GGA(my_sentence)

                    result_gps.put((lat, lon, alt))
                except UnicodeDecodeError:
                    pass
    else:
        device_xbee=Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 57600)
        device_xbee.write(str.encode(data_queue.get()))
        print('data sent')
```

The problem is that when trying to send data using Xbee the data received from GPS become corrupt instead, while it can still get some data, the process become very slow. At first i thought this was because of the multiprocessing, so i tried to do them alternately using multiprocessing.Lock(), but it still failed. Trying to do them alternately with the code above still result in the same error. There's no problem with the GPS Data as when the code to send data with Xbee is not used the GPS data is normal.

Next i thought that maybe it was because of the serial port, however changing xbee's port to ttyUSB1 still result in the same problem. I have also tried to link ttyUSB0 to ttyS3 and as expected merely linking it doesn't work either. So, is this problem because ttyUSB and ttyS use the same serial port? and is there a way to go around this problem?

PS: the gps used is NEOM8N

Here's a screenshot of the corrupted message
[image]
Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Please see *["I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)*

Answer (score 0):

I would go back and confirm the names of each serial port. ttyUSB0 should not be the same as ttyS0.  Plug the XBee in and look at `dmesg` to see what the device name is.

Open each comm port once and keep it open, don't keep reopening it. The code you posted is odd because the function cannot return from the while True loop:   if it did then you would reopen the first serial port again, this can cause data loss and may be your issue. the serial connection to the Xbee is always recreated, again probably not a good idea

Multiprocessing should not cause a problem here as the devices should be on separate ports.  If you can get a read thread working and posting to a queue, you are half way there.  The second process can read from the queue and write to the other port.

Your original idea should work well, the processes should not be able to interfere with each others interaction with the serial ports.